# I receive an Exception When reflecting java interface

Tags: java, reflect

I want to reflect an interface in one of my SDK and call it, but I received an exception. The following is my code. Please help me solve this problem

```
public class ReflectMain {
Class<?> obs = null;
InterProxy.ProxyCallback callback = new InterProxy.ProxyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onInvoke() {
        Log.d("totolog", "invokeSuccess");
    }
};

public void reflectinterMain() {


    try {
        Class<?> reflectClass = Class.forName(ReflectClass.class.getName());
        obs = Class.forName(ReflectClass.ReflectInter.class.getName());
        Method method = reflectClass.getDeclaredMethod("addInter", obs);
        Object listener = Proxy.newProxyInstance(obs.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{obs}, new InterProxy(callback));
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke("addInter", new Object[]{listener});
        obs.newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class InterProxy implements InvocationHandler {
public ProxyCallback callback = null;
interface ProxyCallback {
    void onInvoke();
}

InterProxy(ProxyCallback callback) {
    if (this.callback != null) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }
}

@Override
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    Log.d("totolog", method.getName());
    if ("onRefletc".equals(method.getName())) {
        callback.onInvoke();
    }

    return proxy;
}
```

And Reflect Class

```
class ReflectClass {

public ReflectInter inter = null;

void addInter(ReflectInter reflectInter) {
    inter = reflectInter;
    invoInter();
}

interface ReflectInter {
    public void onRefletc();
}

private void invoInter() {
    inter.onRefletc();
}
```

Then I received such an exception. Please help me analyze the cause of this exception and how to solve it.

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type lab.mon.actlab.java.reflectInter.ReflectClass, but got java.lang.String
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at lab.mon.actlab.java.reflectInter.ReflectMain.reflectinterMain(ReflectMain.java:29)
    at lab.mon.actlab.java.reflect.ReflectActivity.onResume(ReflectActivity.java:87)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1354)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3620)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3685) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2898) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

How can I fix it, I want to know why?

Comment: What line is causing the error?  Show the full stack trace,

Comment: I had added my the full stack

Comment: It looks like `method.invoke("addInter", new Object[]{listener});` means you're calling the addInter method and passing the param `addInter`.  That method expects a `ReflectInter` param.

Comment: This did not worked for me`InterProxy.ProxyCallback callback = new InterProxy.ProxyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onInvoke() {
        Log.d("totolog", "invokeSuccess");
    }
};` instead added   `InterProxy interProxy = new InterProxy(new ProxyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onInvoke() {
            Log.d("totolog", "invokeSuccess");
        }
    });`

Comment: I fix that, thank u everyone

Answer (score 1):

The call to `method.invoke` is not correct since it expects as the first parameter an instance of the object on which you want to invoke the method. You're passing the name of the method.